# MongoDB $in operator query performance with boolean values

Tags: mongodb

Does my query performance get affected if I used

```
db.collection.find({field:{$in:[true,false]}})
```

I mean I know it's the same thing like

```
db.collection.find({})
```

But I may some cases where it could be like the first query. So, is it going to affect my query performance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Query performance depends upon many factors, like - indexes, the amount of data, the hardware (RAM, CPU, network, etc.). The query shape can also affect. That said, what is the expected performance you are looking for is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, the simple `find` will be faster. Because

1. It doesn't need to check any index
2. It doesn't need to do any filter

Whereas the other query

`db.collection.find({field:{$in:[true,false]}})`

1. If you have an index on `field` then the performance will be better but depends on the total amount of data, cluster resources, schema, etc.
2. If you do not have an index, it will be slower than #1 as it has to do `COLSCAN`.

Again, these are all theories. You should try it out with different amounts of data in your cluster and benchmark the results as recommended in the documentation.

When do you need `db.collection.find({field:{$in:[true,false]}})` in your case?

It would help if you had this where you have documents that do not fall under either `true` or `false`. Otherwise, you can use simple `find`.

Comment: I am trying to implement a multi-filter functionality on a specific endpoint in `Express.js`. Where I check if a field called `offerInternships` exists in the `req.query` so it can look like this for example `http://localhost:3000/api/resource?offerInternships=true`, it can be false either. But, if that `req.query` didn't exist in the first place, so I'd call `db.collection.find({offerInternships:{$in:[true,false]}})`

That's why I was asking, but I guess I found a way around to avoid using any filters.